# Leaflet: auto change color of cluster / or spiderfy to chosen marker in cluster.

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markerclusterer

I am current practicing on [Leaftlet Marker Cluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster).

1.
If I know the marker I need is under a cluster, how can I automatically spiderfy that cluster to the max zoom level that obtain the marker I need without clicking onto the cluster?

2.
If I know the marker in that cluster, how can I auto changing color of that cluster so I know that the marker I need to find is under that cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Down the page](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#other-group-methods) on the github repo you listed above, I found this method that might answer your first question:

> - zoomToShowLayer(layer, callback): Zooms to show the given marker (spiderfying if required), calls the callback when the marker is visible on the map.

2. It looks like [these methods](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#refreshing-the-clusters-icon) could be used to update the styling for a single cluster based on a single marker within that cluster:

> If you have customized the clusters icon to use some data from the contained markers, and later that data changes, use this method to force a refresh of the cluster icons. You can use the method:
>   ...
>
> - with a single marker.

Specifically:

```
// If updating only one marker, pass true to
// refresh this marker's parent clusters right away.
myMarker.refreshIconOptions(optionsMap, true);
```

Comment: clusterMarkers.zoomToShowLayer(m, function(){m.openPopup();})